# Unsigned char automatically promoted to int in function call, why?

Tags: c++

Why is an `unsigned char` automatically promoted to an `int` when calling a function? In the example below there is an `f(int)` and a `f(char)` function. It seemed more logical that the compiler would coerce an `unsigned char` argument to a `char` and call `f(char)` since they have the same number of bits. It is calling `f(int)` instead, even when that means promoting the argument to a type with more bits. Any pointers to where the rule is defined? Standard or compiler/platform specific?

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int key )
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

void f( char key )
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    unsigned char c = 'c';

    f(a);
    f(b);
    f(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Produces this output:

```
void f(int)
void f(char)
void f(int)
```

Comment: All the possible values of an `unsigned char` can be represented by an `int`.  They can't all be represented by a signed `char`.

Answer (score 12):

Because `unsigned char` cannot be represented by `char`. For example, if they're both 8 bits, and your unsigned char contains the value `255`, that overflows the `signed char` - and signed integer overflow invokes undefined behavior. Anyway, printable characters are generally expected to be stored in `char` and not `unsigned char` (and C strings are of type `char[]` and not `unsigned char[]`, etc.)

So the promotion to `int` is necessary to represent values greater than `1 << (CHAR_BIT - 1)`.

Comment: But note M3taSpl0it's answer below: whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation determined so, in theory, this code will vary in behaviour by compiler.

Comment: @JackAidley Yes, it will, but in this particular example (and in most implementations) it is signed.

Comment: Indeed, but it is still worth noting in general

Answer (score 7):

I believe the correct derivation from the Standard is based on the paragraph below, which is found section 13.3.3 *Best viable functions*, i.e. it's part of the (very complicated) rules for function overload resolution.

> (§13.3.3.2/4) Standard conversion sequences are ordered by their ranks: an Exact Match is a better conversion than a Promotion, which is a better conversion than a Conversion. Two conversion sequences with the same rank are indistinguishable unless one of the following rules applies: [...]

Converting `unsigned char` to `int` is classified as *promotion* (defined in §4.5; when reading the below, note that `(unsigned) char` is an *integer type*):

> §4.5 Integral promotions
>   [...]
>
> (§4.5/2) A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.

Whereas converting `unsigned char` to `char` is not classified as *promotion* because their ranks are identical:

> (§4.13/1) [...] The rank of char shall equal the rank of signed char and unsigned char. [...]

It is classified as *integral conversion* (§4.7) instead, and, as described above, promotion is preferred over conversion during overload resolution.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ standard , `char` isn't defined to be unsigned or signed (though size is 1 byte) , so it's implementation defined. So in your implementation I believe it's signed char that's why it got promoted.

Answer (score -1):

int and char are just different in range in C and C++, if char it ranges from 0 to 255 and if int, it has its range like 65535 (range of int will vary with OS). So compiler just treat it as int.

Comment: char (signed) actually ranges from -128 to 127 and it is not the same as unsigned char, which ranges from 0 to 255.

Comment: So while passing as argument, compiler distinguish between signed and unsigned?

Comment: see [here](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/docs/faqs/signedchar.php) for an example. It is based on ARM, but many platforms should face the same problems. Generally it is not good idea to mix them.